# The Equation of Motion of a Snowball

Tags: calculus, differential

I'm trying to derive the equation of motion of a snowball down a slope, given some known factors, in the form of either its angular acceleration, acceleration, velocity, or angular velocity expressed as a function of time. I've reached this point;

$$g\sin \theta=6w\frac{dr}{dt}+\frac 75 \frac{rdw}{dt}$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle of incline of the slope, $w$ is its angular velocity, $r$ is its radius, and $g$ is gravity. $dr/dt$ is rate of change of radius and $dw/dt$ is rate of change of angular velocity. 
I now need to integrate this in such a way that radius is expressed as some function of angular velocity. The original question I was following at this point assumed that theta was equal to zero (i.e the slope is flat) in order to simplify calculations. I'm not sure how to work with a differential equation when there seems to be 3 variables. Please help.

Comment: Please use Mathjax from next time. Check if I correctly translated the expression.

Comment: And I believe you will need to use another physics equation. The equation as it stands cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of angular velocity we can argue that:$$r\omega=gt\sin \theta $$ or $$\frac{1}{\omega}=\frac{r}{gt\sin\theta}$$ also we can write the differential equation of question as following:$$g\sin \theta=4.6(\omega\frac{dr}{dt})+1.4(\omega\frac{dr}{dt}+r\frac{d\omega}{dt})=4.6(\omega\frac{dr}{dt})+1.4g\sin \theta$$finally we have:$${-0.4g\sin\theta}\frac{1}{\omega}=4.6\frac{dr}{dt}$$ this leads to $$-0.4\frac{r}{t}=4.6\frac{dr}{dt}\to \ln t=C-11.5\ln r\to r=Ct^{-\frac{2}{23}}\quad,\quad \omega=Cg\sin\theta t^{\frac{25}{23}}$$

Comment: I failed to mention this in the first post, my bad, but there's a friction force acting opposing to the ball's motion. I should probably ask this in the physics stack exchange at this point shouldn't I?

Comment: It's OK but you'd attain better answers if you ask there but the extra equation is always true whether there is any friction or not...

Comment: Wouldn't it change now since velocity isnt equal to mgsin(theta) multiplied by time, but rather (mgsin(theta) - friction) multiplied by time?

Comment: if you put the origin of your coordinates on the center of the snowball you will easily get it. You don't need to be worry about friction or its effect since it has been considered before...

Comment: But won't it change (d(rw)/dt) is equal to and change the equation written in the 4th step above?